# Is a free category in some formal sense the “opposite” of a poset category?

Tags: category-theory

I know that the free functor is adjoint to the forgetful functor, which makes me doubt my hypothesis, but:

My thought is: If you start out with a diagram, and you generate a free category with it, what you are doing is: “taking all the compositions and **distinguishing between the result based on how you did the composition**”

But when you take the same diagram, and you generate a poset category from it, i.e. make sure that there is only one arrow for each pair of objects, what you’re doing is “taking all the compositions and **ignoring the difference between how you took the composition**”.

**In some intuitive sense, they are opposite. Is there a formal sense that makes this precise? Is there some adjointness relation between some formalization of these concepts?**

Comment: The poset category seems to be a subcategory of your "free" category. How are they opposite? I don't see that intuition.

Comment: @freakish No, it's a quotient category.

Comment: @KevinCarlson And? Not subcategory in strict sense. It naturally embeds into it. Unless I misunderstand what this "free" category is.

Comment: I think what you're getting at is we can start with a free category on some quiver with a fixed set of objects. We can then imagine a family of equivalence relations indexed by pairs of objects on the corresponding homset such that this family is compatible with the categorical structure. Quotienting each homset by the corresponding equivalence relation gives a new category. We have a lattice induced by the refinement relation on equivalence relations. The extremes of this lattice will be the free category itself and the corresponding thin category.

Comment: @freakish The poset category only has one morphism between any two objects. There's no natural choice of such a morphism in the free category.

Comment: @freakish Consider the "square" directed graph with edges $f\colon A\to B$, $g\colon B\to D$, $f'\colon A\to C$, and $g'\colon C\to D$. In free category on this directed graph, we have $g\circ f\neq g'\circ f'$. But in the poset generated by this directed graph, we have $g\circ f = g'\circ f'$ (because all diagrams commute in a poset!). Now it's easy to check that there is no embedding from the poset into the free category.